# How to render the autodesk model in offline mode in IIS(windows) web server?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I'm making an asp.net web app and have used the forge api to render the model in offline mode. The problem (image below) i'm having is to render the model in offline mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are missing all the viewer rendering and support files to get the viewer working properly. Checkout [this file](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/master/server/viewer.js) for details of missing files. Note that the full list is built from code as it expands from parameters. The easiest way to get the missing files would be to use [this site](https://extract.autodesk.io/) to extract one model (any), and copy the Res directory which will contains the missing files.

Comment: thanks, I really get the model from the site https://extract.autodesk.io/, and when I finished deploying my web app in IIS, the problem appears as follows: THREE.DDSLoader.parse: Invalid magic number in DDS header. viewer3D.min.js:1:1161
 init_three_dds_loader/THREE.DDSLoader.parse 
 THREE.CompressedTextureLoader.prototype.load/< 
 THREE.XHRLoader.prototype.load/<

Comment: I just tried with 2 models and all works fine for me - which one did you try? and did you clear your cache to make sure you do not have legacy files in your browser cache?

Comment: I tried my own model from extract.autodesk.io, and I got all rendering and support files. In my asp.net web app, all rendering files were integreted in. The offline model can work well in asp.net development server(equal to run in visual studio), but not work well after deploying it in IIS. Problem and error is as above. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: I believe you got an issue on your IIS configuration. Make sure that you do allow http on these new directories.

Comment: Thank you very much! I checked my IIS configuration seriously, then found the reason, and finally solved it.